# Structure of GNU/Linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I have some basic knowledge about Linux OS like it consist of Kernel.The kernel is core of Linux , It manages all processes, device drivers, and I/O.But My Question is what Linux consists of beside Kernel , Binaries , Device Files  and Libs ? 
Linux Distro's are Open Source so how do I compile whole distro myself ? Like Compiling Whole Arch Linux or Ubuntu Linux on my own then installing it on my computer ?

Comment: You should consider to star with something like [linux from scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/) to understand better the concept of linux distribution.

Comment: Linux is just the kernel, or it is the whole distro (better called Gnu/Linux).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Linux Distro's are Open Source so how do I compile whole distro myself ?

Compiling your own is an excellent way to learn what it consists of.  Fortunately, there are linux distributions that are designed to be compiled by end-users and it would be easier to start with one of those.  There is a list of such distributions [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aSource-based_Linux_distributions).  [Gentoo](http://www.gentoo.org/) is probably the most popular among them.

Comment: What about other distro's ?

Comment: @Sigma If you pick a distro that was designed for binary distribution, like Ubuntu, it would still be possible to compile it yourself but it would be a whole lot more effort and, likely, frustration on your part than if you picked a distro that is designed from scratch for end-user compilation.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to learn something about linux and how to setup a system from scratch I would recommend you [LSF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_From_Scratch) (Linux From Scratch). It is nothing more than a manual on "How to build your own linux". Even Arch Linux was build from this manual, if you check the history.

Answer (score 0):

Compiling the whole shebang by yourself will only teach you how to stare at the screen. A Linux distribution is some 30 million lines of code, getting to grasp that is a job for more than a lifetime. Better select some part of it that particularly interests you, and get involved in it's development.